# Efficiently sum complex matrix products with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix, `X`, for which I am computing a weighted sum of intermediate matrix products. Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np

random_state = np.random.RandomState(1)
n = 5
p = 10

X = random_state.rand(p, n) # 10x5
X_sum = np.zeros((n, n)) # 5x5

# The length of weights are not related to X's dims,
# but will always be smaller
y = 3
weights = random_state.rand(y)

for k in range(y):
    X_sum += np.dot(X.T[:, k + 1:],
                    X[:p - (k + 1), :]) * weights[k]
```

This works fine and produces the results I expect. However, as the size of `n` and `y` grow (into the hundreds), this becomes extremely expensive, as repetitively computing matrix products is not exactly efficient...

There is an obvious pattern in how the products are computed, however:

[image: First iteration]

[image: Second iteration]

You can see as the iterations progress, the starting column slice in `Xt` moves to the right, while the ending row in `X` moves up. Here's what the Nth iteration would look like:

[image: Nth iteration]

This effectively means a subset of the same values are being repeatedly multiplied (see **edit 2**), which seems to me there may be an opportunity to exploit... (i.e., if I were to manually compute the product in one pass).

But I'm hoping not to have to do anything manually and that there may be a nice way to achieve this whole loop more elegantly with Numpy.

#### Edit 1

A realistic set of numbers:

```
n = 400
p = 2000
y = 750
```

#### Edit 2

To address the comment:

> Could you explain what values are repeatedly multiplied?

Consider the following array:

```
n = p = 5
X = np.arange(25).reshape(p, n)
```

For `k=0`, the first product will be between `A` and `B`:

```
k = 0
A = X.T[:, k + 1:]
B = X[:p - (k + 1), :]
>>> A
array([[ 5, 10, 15, 20],
       [ 6, 11, 16, 21],
       [ 7, 12, 17, 22],
       [ 8, 13, 18, 23],
       [ 9, 14, 19, 24]])
>>> B
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

And when `k=1`:

```
k = 1
>>> A
array([[10, 15, 20],
       [11, 16, 21],
       [12, 17, 22],
       [13, 18, 23],
       [14, 19, 24]])
>>> B
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

So each subsequent matrix product is something of a subset of the previous product, if that makes sense.

Comment: Could you explain what values are repeatedly multiplied? From your examples it looks like that in each iteration the same rows and columns are multiplied but t every iteration it is a different combination of numbers from these rows/columns so in that sense there is no duplication. Or are you just worried about getting the `for` loop into numpy?

Comment: @a_guest I added an edit to explain. Essentially, each subsequent matrix product contains a subset of the previous matrix product. So, for example, in the second case where `k=1`, a portion of the product will be `[10, 15, 20] * [0, 5, 10]`, which has technically already been computed in the step before with `[5, 10, 15, 20] * [0, 5, 10, 15]`. Of course, this is only relevant were I to compute the whole thing manually, if that makes sense.

Comment: It is not clear to me how subsequent matrix products are contained in previous ones. Coming back to your example for `k = 0` it is `[5, 10, 15, 20] * [0, 5, 10, 15]` and for `k = 1` it is `[10, 15, 20] * [0, 5, 10]` and each of the *operands* is a sub-list of the previous operands (i.e. `[10, 15, 20] < [5, 10, 15, 20]`) but the combinations that arise from the product are not contained in previous computations: `5*0 + 10*5 + 15*10 + 20*15` and `10*0 + 15*5 + 20*10`, so the relevant sub-list of the second operand is multiplied by different values than before, i.e. there is no duplication.

Comment: If I'm not computing manually, it doesn't matter. Ideally I wouldn't be anyways. Consider that an aside as I thought about how to make this more simple. I think it's just caused confusion.

Comment: The question, in its simplest form, is whether Numpy has anything that would allow me to achieve this more efficiently. Forget the duplication remark

Comment: Okay so we agree that there is no duplication in terms of the summands that arise from the various matrix products of different size? Just to make sure that the structure of the problem is clear. So the question is about how to vectorize the for loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185952/discussion-between-tgsmith61591-and-a-guest).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR; I would opt for @Parfait's use of `test_gen_sum` based on benchmarking across various values of `n`, `p`, and `y`. Keeping old answer here for continuity's sake**.

### Assess how `n`, `p`, `y` affect choice of algorithm

This analysis is done using @Parfait's functions as a means of determining if there is really *one* best solution or if there are a family of solutions based on values of `n`, `p`, and `y`.

```
import numpy as np
import pytest # This code also requires the pytest-benchmark plugin

def test_for_sum(n, p, y):
    random_state = np.random.RandomState(1)
    X = random_state.rand(p, n)
    X_sum = np.zeros((n, n))

    # The length of weights are not related to X's dims,
    # but will always be smaller
    weights = random_state.rand(y)

    for k in range(y):
        X_sum += np.dot(X.T[:, k + 1:],
                    X[:p - (k + 1), :]) * weights[k]

    return X_sum


def test_list_sum(n, p, y):
    random_state = np.random.RandomState(1)

    X = random_state.rand(p, n)
    X_sum = np.zeros((n, n))

    # The length of weights are not related to X's dims,
    # but will always be smaller
    weights = random_state.rand(y)

    matrix_list = [np.dot(X.T[:, k + 1:],
                      X[:p - (k + 1), :]) * weights[k] for k in range(y)]

    X_sum = np.sum(matrix_list, axis=0)

    return X_sum


def test_reduce_sum(n, p, y):
    random_state = np.random.RandomState(1)

    X = random_state.rand(p, n)
    X_sum = np.zeros((n, n))

    # The length of weights are not related to X's dims,
    # but will always be smaller
    weights = random_state.rand(y)

    matrix_list = [(X.T[:, k + 1:] @
                X[:p - (k + 1), :]) * weights[k] for k in range(y)]

    X_sum = reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, matrix_list)

    return X_sum


def test_concat_sum(n, p, y):
    random_state = np.random.RandomState(1)

    X = random_state.rand(p, n)
    X_sum = np.zeros((n, n))

    # The length of weights are not related to X's dims,
    # but will always be smaller
    weights = random_state.rand(y)

    x_mat = np.concatenate([np.matmul(X.T[:, k + 1:],
                                  X[:p - (k + 1), :]) for k in range(y)])

    wgt_mat = np.concatenate([np.full((n,1), weights[k]) for k in range(y)])

    mul_res = x_mat * wgt_mat        
    X_sum = mul_res.reshape(-1, n, n).sum(axis=0)

    return X_sum


def test_matmul_sum(n, p, y):
    random_state = np.random.RandomState(1)
    X = random_state.rand(p, n)
    X_sum = np.zeros((n, n))

    # The length of weights are not related to X's dims,
    # but will always be smaller
    weights = random_state.rand(y)
    # Use list comprehension and np.matmul 
    matrices_list = [np.matmul(X.T[:, k + 1:],
                           X[:p - (k + 1), :]) * weights[k] for k in range(y)]

    # Sum matrices in list of matrices to get the final result   
    X_sum = np.sum(matrices_list, axis=0)

    return X_sum


def test_gen_sum(n, p, y):
    random_state = np.random.RandomState(1)

    X = random_state.rand(p, n)
    X_sum = np.zeros((n, n))

    # The length of weights are not related to X's dims,
    # but will always be smaller
    weights = random_state.rand(y)

    matrix_gen = (np.dot(X.T[:, k + 1:],
                     X[:p - (k + 1), :]) * weights[k] for k in range(y))

    X_sum = sum(matrix_gen)

    return X_sum

parameters = [
    pytest.param(400, 800, 3)
    ,pytest.param(400, 2000, 3)
    ,pytest.param(400, 800, 750)
    ,pytest.param(400, 2000, 750)
]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('n,p,y', parameters)
def test_test_for_sum(benchmark, n, p, y):
    benchmark(test_for_sum, n=n, p=p, y=y)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('n,p,y', parameters)
def test_test_list_sum(benchmark, n, p, y):
     benchmark(test_list_sum, n=n, p=p, y=y)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('n,p,y', parameters)
def test_test_reduce_sum(benchmark, n, p, y):
    benchmark(test_reduce_sum, n=n, p=p, y=y)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('n,p,y', parameters)
def test_test_concat_sum(benchmark, n, p, y):
    benchmark(test_concat_sum, n=n, p=p, y=y)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('n,p,y', parameters)
def test_test_matmul_sum(benchmark, n, p, y):
    benchmark(test_matmul_sum, n=n, p=p, y=y)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('n,p,y', parameters)
def test_test_gen_sum(benchmark, n, p, y):
    benchmark(test_gen_sum, n=n, p=p, y=y)
```

- `n=400`, `p=800`, `y=3` (100 iterations)

  - **winner:** `test_gen_sum`
    [image]
- `n=400`, `p=2000`, `y=3` (100 iterations)

  - **winner:** `test_gen_sum`
    [image]
- `n=400`, `p=800`, `y=750` (10 iterations)

  - **winner:** `test_gen_sum`
    [image]
- `n=400`, `p=2000`, `y=750` (10 iterations)

  - **winner:** `test_gen_sum`
    [image]

## OLD ANSWER

### Smaller `y` values

I would definitely use [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy-matmul) instead of `np.dot` this will get you the biggest boost in performance and in fact the documentation for [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) will direct you to `np.matmul` for 2D array multiplication in lieu of `np.dot`.

I tested both `np.dot` and `np.matmul` with and without list comprehension and the [pytest-benchmark](https://pytest-benchmark.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) results are here:

[image: y=3]

Btw **pytest-benchmark** is pretty slick and I highly recommend it at times like this to validate if an approach is truly performant.

Just using list comprehension has an almost negligible effect on `np.matmul` results and a negative effect on `np.dot` (albeit that is better form) in the scheme of things, but the combination of both changes yielded the best results in terms. I would warn that using list comprehensions tend to drive up the std. dev. of the runtime so you may see larger ranges in runtime performance than if you were to just use `np.matmul`.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

def test_np_matmul_list_comprehension():
    random_state = np.random.RandomState(1)
    n = p = 1000
    X = np.arange(n * n).reshape(p, n)

    # The length of weights are not related to X's dims,
    # but will always be smaller
    y = 3
    weights = [1, 1, 1]
    # Use list comprehension and np.matmul 
    matrices_list = [np.matmul(X.T[:, k + 1:],
                             X[:p - (k + 1), :]) * weights[k] for k in range(y)]

    # Sum matrices in list of matrices to get the final result   
    X_sum = np.sum(matrices_list, axis=0)
```

### Larger `y` values

For larger values of `y` you are better off not using list comprehension. The mean/median runtime tends to be larger for both `np.dot` and `np.matmul` in both of those cases. Here are the `pytest-benchmark` results for (`n=500`,`p=5000`,`y=750`):

[image]

This is probably overkill, but I would rather err on the side of being too helpful :).

Answer (score 3):

Consider the follow re-factored versions compared to the iterative sum calls in `for` loop. The new versions using `reduce`, generator, and `np.concatenate` result marginally faster but still comparable to `for` loop. Each runs with `n = 400, p = 800, y = 750`.

**OP Original version**

```
import numpy as np

def test_for_sum():
    random_state = np.random.RandomState(1)
    n= 400
    p = 800

    X = random_state.rand(p, n)
    X_sum = np.zeros((n, n))

    # The length of weights are not related to X's dims,
    # but will always be smaller
    y = 750
    weights = random_state.rand(y)

    for k in range(y):
        X_sum += np.dot(X.T[:, k + 1:],
                        X[:p - (k + 1), :]) * weights[k]

    return X_sum
```

**List Comprehension with np.dot**

```
def test_list_sum():
    random_state = np.random.RandomState(1)
    n= 400
    p = 800

    X = random_state.rand(p, n)
    X_sum = np.zeros((n, n))

    # The length of weights are not related to X's dims,
    # but will always be smaller
    y = 750
    weights = random_state.rand(y)

    matrix_list = [np.dot(X.T[:, k + 1:],
                          X[:p - (k + 1), :]) * weights[k] for k in range(y)]

    X_sum = sum(matrix_list)

    return X_sum
```

**Generator Version**

```
def test_gen_sum():
    random_state = np.random.RandomState(1)
    n= 400
    p = 800

    X = random_state.rand(p, n)
    X_sum = np.zeros((n, n))

    # The length of weights are not related to X's dims,
    # but will always be smaller
    y = 750
    weights = random_state.rand(y)

    matrix_gen = (np.dot(X.T[:, k + 1:],
                         X[:p - (k + 1), :]) * weights[k] for k in range(y))

    X_sum = sum(matrix_gen)

    return X_sum
```

**Reduce Version** *(using new `@` operator --syntactic sugar-- in place of `np.matmul`)*

```
from functools import reduce

def test_reduce_sum():
    random_state = np.random.RandomState(1)
    n= 400
    p = 800

    X = random_state.rand(p, n)
    X_sum = np.zeros((n, n))

    # The length of weights are not related to X's dims,
    # but will always be smaller
    y = 750
    weights = random_state.rand(y)

    matrix_list = [(X.T[:, k + 1:] @
                    X[:p - (k + 1), :]) * weights[k] for k in range(y)]

    X_sum = reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, matrix_list)

    return X_sum
```

**Concatenate Version**

```
def test_concat_sum():
    random_state = np.random.RandomState(1)
    n= 400
    p = 800

    X = random_state.rand(p, n)
    X_sum = np.zeros((n, n))

    # The length of weights are not related to X's dims,
    # but will always be smaller
    y = 750
    weights = random_state.rand(y)

    x_mat = np.concatenate([np.matmul(X.T[:, k + 1:],
                                      X[:p - (k + 1), :]) for k in range(y)])

    wgt_mat = np.concatenate([np.full((n,1), weights[k]) for k in range(y)])

    mul_res = x_mat * wgt_mat        
    X_sum = mul_res.reshape(-1, n, n).sum(axis=0)

    return X_sum
```

**List Comprehension with np.matmul**

```
def test_matmul_sum():
    random_state = np.random.RandomState(1)
    n = 400
    p = 800
    X = random_state.rand(p, n)
    X_sum = np.zeros((n, n))

    # The length of weights are not related to X's dims,
    # but will always be smaller
    y = 750
    weights = random_state.rand(y)
    # Use list comprehension and np.matmul 
    matrices_list = [np.matmul(X.T[:, k + 1:],
                               X[:p - (k + 1), :]) * weights[k] for k in range(y)]

    # Sum matrices in list of matrices to get the final result   
    X_sum = np.sum(matrices_list, axis=0)

    return X_sum
```

---

### Timings

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
res_for = test_for_sum()
print("SUM: {} seconds ---".format(time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
res_list = test_list_sum()
print("LIST: {} seconds ---".format(time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
res_gen = test_gen_sum()
print("GEN: {} seconds ---".format(time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
res_reduce= test_reduce_sum()
print("REDUCE: {} seconds ---".format(time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
res_concat = test_concat_sum()
print("CONCAT: {} seconds ---".format(time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
res_matmul = test_matmul_sum()
print("MATMUL: {} seconds ---".format(time.time() - start_time))
```

Equality Tests

```
print(np.array_equal(res_for, res_list))
# True
print(np.array_equal(res_for, res_gen))
# True
print(np.array_equal(res_for, res_reduce))
# True
print(np.array_equal(res_for, res_concat))
# True
print(np.array_equal(res_for, res_matmul))
# True
```

**First Run**

```
# SUM: 21.569773197174072 seconds ---
# LIST: 23.576102018356323 seconds ---
# GEN: 21.385253429412842 seconds ---
# REDUCE: 21.426464080810547 seconds ---
# CONCAT: 21.059731483459473 seconds ---
# MATMUL: 23.57494807243347 seconds ---
```

**Second Run**

```
# SUM: 21.6339168548584 seconds ---
# LIST: 19.767740488052368 seconds ---
# GEN: 23.86947798728943 seconds ---
# REDUCE: 19.880712032318115 seconds ---
# CONCAT: 20.761067152023315 seconds ---
# MATMUL: 23.55513620376587 seconds ---
```

**Third Run**

```
# SUM: 22.764745473861694 seconds ---
# LIST: 19.953850984573364 seconds ---
# GEN: 24.37714171409607 seconds ---
# REDUCE: 22.54508638381958 seconds ---
# CONCAT: 21.20585823059082 seconds ---
# MATMUL: 22.303589820861816 seconds ---
```

Comment: Doesn't this come at a significantly increased memory consumption? Instead of maintaining one `n x n` matrix now there are `y` `n x n` matrices stored in the list. Especially for the realistic values in the OP where `n = 400` and `y = 750` the impact should be noticeable. Also could you back your statements with some timings please? On my computer this approach runs actually slower (7.56 s ± 293 ms vs. 6.91 s ± 184 ms).

Comment: @Parfait I like your use of a generator and the reduce function! Strangely all my efforts to duplicate your results seemed to yield that the generator was better than the other methods for various values of `n`, `p`, and `y`. Anyway you got my upvote :).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDrotar for the benchmarking! I am still convinced there is vectorized solution to this, entirely avoiding `for` calls. Work in progress...